# help selecting robot hardware

Tags: ros, real-time, hardware, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

so i need a pc to run my robot..what if i use some intel mother board with intel atom or pentium, linux runing on it to control the robot is it possible?? suggest me some controller ?? instead of running in linux platform can i go fo rtlinux or win ce ?? will it work real time in those platform /
viki

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52468/help-selecting-robot-hardware/) by [viki](https://answers.ros.org/users/3971/viki/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2013-01-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) on 2013-01-16**:
You might get better responses if you describe the features of your robot (size, arms, sensors), and what the robot will have to do.

**Comment by [viki](https://answers.ros.org/users/3971/viki/) on 2013-01-16**:
it like wheel chair with robotic ability developed for disabled people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For [UAV hardware](http://ibotics.ucsd.edu/trac/stingray/query?group=status&milestone=New+Hardware), that link will show you what hardware we selected. This is not an identical platform since we were aiming for underwater use, but it could help show what we used to control motors, perform stereo vision algorithms, and do planning.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2013-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0